# Von Neumann Entropy of $n$ qubits

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy, quantum-entanglement

Why is the maximum entropy of $n$ qubits (in $\log_2$ units) equal to $n$? How does one calculate $\operatorname{Tr}(\rho \operatorname{log} \rho)$ (since $\log \rho$ must be expanded). What is even the density matrix of this state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\rho$ in its eigenbasis. The eigenvalues are probabilities $p_i$, $\sum p_i=1$. Then,
$$
-\mathrm{tr}(\rho\log\rho)=-\sum p_i\log p_i\ .
$$
You should now be able to easily see which $p_i$ maximizes this quantity (which is just the classical Shannon entropy).

(If you want to formalize this, you need to use the concept of [Schur-convexity/concavity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur-convex_function) and majorization: $-\sum p_i\log p_i$ is Schur-concave and thus maximized by the distribution which is majorized by all other ones.)